# Як буде заусенка українською?

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Стало цікаво, як перекласти слово заусенка (заусеница) українською?

Заусенец, заусеница (лат. reduvial) — разрыв кожи ногтевого валика.

Знайшла такі цікаві варіанти:

ЗАУСЕНИЦА 
заді[и]рка, задра, задьора, занігтиця, задерка. [Коли руки втерти в мішок, то будуть задри на пальцях (Франко). То од землі такі задьори поробилися (Козел. п.)].

Який краще застосовувати? Задирка?

Comment: Слово «краще» є ознакою primarily opinion-based question. Якщо вас цікавить якийсь науково-обґрунтований критерій вибору якогось варіанту серед наведених, то цей критерій варто вказати.

Answer (score 5):

Трішки виправлю [Iva_ukr](/a/4829) — насправді *всі* зазначені Вами варіанти містяться в словниках, *і навіть більше*:

> заде́ра
>   заде́рка
>   задера́чка
>   задира́чка
>   зади́рга
>   за́ди́рка
>   за́дірка
>   за́дра
>   за́дьора
>   зані́гтиця
>   зано́гтиця

— зокрема «Російсько-український словник» Кримського і Єфремова (1924–1933), «Словник українсько-російський Ніковського» (1927), «Словарь української мови» Грінченка (1909), «Російсько-український словник військової термінології» Якубських (1928), «Словарь росийсько-український» Уманця й Спілки (1893–1898) [наприклад, на [R2U](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0&scope=rus&dicts=all&highlight=on)], «Українсько-англійський словник» Андрусишина й Крета (1955) [наприклад, на [E2U](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=hangnail&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on)].

Але в **сучасних** більш-менш серйозних словниках я бачу лише один:

> за́дирка

— зокрема в [«Словнику української мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=29011&page=961) і [«Словниках України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/). Тож, можливо, варто надавати перевагу йому. Принаймні, якщо у Вас нема сильних особистих уподобань до інших слів.

Answer (score 3):

Слово [задирка](http://sum.in.ua/s/zadyrka) знаходимо у СУМі та в [Орфографічному словнику](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=21&t=98593), тому нормативно його використовувати:

> **ЗА́ДИРКА,** и, жін. Задерта шкірочка коло нігтя.
>
> **ЗА́ДИ́РКА,** и, жін., спец. Задерте місце, шершавість, гострий виступ на гладкій поверхні (дерева, металу і т. ін.). Після різання труб треба старанно зачистити місце розрізу, щоб усунути задирки (Слюсарна справа, 1957, 165).

Однак, не знахдимо в словниках **задірка**, тому краще утриматися від використання цього слова.

Слово [задьора](http://sum.in.ua/s/zadjora) нормативно вживати лише у значенні [задирака](http://sum.in.ua/s/zadyraka), тому краще не використовувати це слово як синонім (хіба у розмовному мовленні):

> **ЗАДИРА́КА**, и, чол. і жін. Людина, що своїми діями, словами призводить до сварки, бійки, бешкету; забіяка, бешкетник.

Слово **занігтиця** знаходимо в [Українсько-російському словнику](https://ukrainian_russian.academic.ru/36981/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B3%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F), та у [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9), однак, у СУМі його немає. Невелика кількість джерел ставить під питання нормативність вживання цього слова, але, очевидно, його можна вживати.

**Задра** і **задерка** немає у словниках, на мою думку, їх можна вживати лише у розмовному мовленні.

Цікаву інформацію щодо слова **ЗАУСЕНИЦА** і його відповідників можна знайти у монографії[Л. Ю. РІДНЕВА. НАРОДНА МЕДИЧНА ЛЕКСИКА РОСІЙСЬКОЇ МОВИ](https://dspace.udpu.edu.ua/jspui/bitstream/6789/1639/1/narodna_leksira_ros_mova.pdf), де згадується ще один відповідник **задорінка**.